# Registration page while using Firebase in Android Studio is not working

Tags: java, android, firebase

I'm trying to make registration while using google firebase but it is not working. The whole activity is irresponsive to the code. I have added few show errors for checking the email and password fields, that also not working. I can type in the EditText fields but when I click register nothing happens. Not even the errors are showing. I am a beginner to android development. What should I do to make it work ?

Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText editTextrollno, editTextuid;
    private MaterialButton login;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private TextView register;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        register = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case  R.id.register:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, RegisterUser.class));
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my RegisterUser.java

```
public class RegisterUser extends AppCompatActivity implements 
    View.OnClickListener { 
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private EditText editTextEmail, editTextUid;
    private TextView signup, register;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_user);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        signup = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signup);
        signup.setOnClickListener(this);

        register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signupbtn);
        register.setOnClickListener(this);

        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        editTextUid = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.uid);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.signup:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                register();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void register() {
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String uid = editTextUid.getText().toString().trim();

        if(email.isEmpty()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Email is required");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(uid.isEmpty()){
            editTextUid.setError("UID is required");
            editTextUid.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
            editTextEmail.setError("Please provide valid Email");
            editTextEmail.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        if(uid.length() < 9){
            editTextUid.setError("Min UID length should be 9 characters");
            editTextUid.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, uid)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            User user = new User(email);

                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .setValue(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Student has been registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    }else{
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });



                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterUser.this, "Failed to register", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });

        }
    }
```

Here is my gradle dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:20.0.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
```

> My AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.loginapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.LoginApp">
        <activity
            android:name=".RegisterUser"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: you need to insert your google key in the manifest if I remember correctly. 
if you're using IJ you can connect your firebase account to your IDE for easy setting.

Comment: @GuySadoun i did connect my firebase account to the app. I am using Android Studio as my IDE

Comment: ok so try to follow this tut: https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup
should be very easy. additionally, look inside your firebase project to see if you're getting any requests. if not it's probably the json file or the key. there is many many tut for those problems. Good luck!

Comment: look here: https://youtu.be/lnidtzL71ZA?t=135 (the exact point where firebase is being connected)
Good luck!

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure everything is setup correctly with Firebase and your application.

Please follow the link and check every steps is finished.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start

Please update your dependencies according to documentation.
[image]

Hope your problem will be fixed soon.